# Add values to a single variable from Array of Maps in java

Tags: java, list, filter, java-stream

suppose we have a List in java containing Maps like this:

```
Arr = [
 {
    "checkno": "322108888           ",
    "amount": 2500,

  },
  {
    "checkno": "321979826           ",
    "amount": 3900,

  }
]
```

i want to add all the amounts to a single variable so as my result for my case will be totalAmount = 6400. So i write this:

```
Arr.stream().forEach(a -> {
 double sum = 0d,
 sum = sum + a.mount
 return sum
})
```

but it does not seem to work fine. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: forEach accept Consumer<T>, Consumer doesn't return anything.

Comment: is this json or a map?

Comment: Read javadocs, this question displays no basic research whatsoever and I believe this should be closed because of that.

Comment: map, sorry for the typo

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arrayOfCheckoutObject).mapToDouble(CheckoutObject::amount).sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class SO58133962 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String,Integer>> nameToCosts = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,Integer> one = new HashMap<>();
    one.put("322108888",2900);
    Map<String,Integer> two = new HashMap<>();
    two.put("321979826",3900);
    nameToCosts.add(one);
    nameToCosts.add(two);

    double sum = nameToCosts.stream().map(Map::values).flatMap(Collection::stream).mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

This should work !

Comment: It’s not necessary to use method references for everything. `.flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())` is simpler than `.map(Map::values).flatMap(Collection::stream)`…

Comment: I don't understand why do you have to make 2 maps and then add them to a list while maps can definitely hold multiple key value pairs.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ashvin , I was just trying to use the original question. ```suppose we have a List in java containing Maps like this```

Answer (score 1):

You can first `map` it to double and call `.sum()`

```
double sum = Arr.stream().mapToDouble(YourClass::getAmount).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the whole program you are trying.

POJO CheckData

```
class CheckData {
private String checkNumber;
private int amount;

public CheckData() {
}

public CheckData(String checkNumber, int amount) {
    super();
    this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getCheckNumber() {
    return checkNumber;
}

public void setCheckNumber(String checkNumber) {
    this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

main class

```
public class Test4 extends Thread {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<CheckData> list = new ArrayList<CheckData>();
    list.add(new CheckData("322108888", 2500));
    list.add(new CheckData("321979826", 3900));

    int sum = list.stream().filter(o -> o.getAmount() > 10).mapToInt(o -> o.getAmount()).sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate the arrayList, get the Map object.
From the map object you can get the value of "amount" key.

```
int amount =0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
    amount += (int) list.get(i).get("amount");
```

Complete working example -

```
class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("checkno", 322108888);
        map.put("amount", 2500);

        list.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("checkno", 321979826);
        map.put("amount", 3900);

        list.add(map);

        int amount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            amount += (int) list.get(i).get("amount");

        System.out.println(amount);

    }
}
```